# Laravel - query where issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have a table `User` and it has a column called `gender`, and `age`. Say I want to get all women who are 18. In the documentation, it says I can do

```
public function scopeGender($query, $gender) {
    return $query->where('gender', '=', $gender);
}

public function scopeAge($query, $age) {
    return $query->where('age', '=', $age);
}
```

and then get my result from `User::gender('F')->age(18)->get()`.

This works just fine. But the documentation has also this implementation:

```
public function scopeWoman($query) {
    return $query->whereGender('F');
}
```

and I wanted to do the same for `age` using:

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age) {
    return $query->whereAge($age);
}
```

But now I get

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereAge()"

Why?

Comment: change you try and change "scopeAge" to "scopeOther" and run ->other(18)   - does that work? I'm wondering if the scopeAge() and whereAge() are conflicting...?

Comment: No it didn't. I still get the same error. Oddly, if I use `whereId($id)` it does work with the ID.